# How to fix sealed consumer product (headphones)?

Tags: repair

So the cable that connects the speakers on [my headphones](http://reviews.cnet.com/headphones/monster-diamond-tears-edge/4505-7877_7-35575777.html) broke. I can tell it's the cable  between them because there is jack input on each speaker and they both play well when connected but the other one is always mute.

I took them to a electrical repair shop and they gave me an estimate 60£ for repair. That's a no go for these old phones.

So my question is, is how do I approach fixing them myself? Everything is sealed and there are no screws. What would the pros do?

Comment: Repair questions are off topic. If the headphones are old and not worth investing 60£ in their repair, why not put that toward a new pair?

Comment: where on SE cna I ask repair/DIY question? This certainly does not belong to home improvement.

Comment: It's not that we don't like repairs, but there are *so* many repair-related questions which are difficult to answer because we 1) can't see/touch the item being repaired; 2) don't know the experience level of the person asking; 3) cannot conduct a conversation which promotes an iterative troubleshooting process like "What did you measure on R4?" "3 volts." "Ok, now let's measure R7." etc. If you can narrow it down to a specific electronics problem, it's more likely to get the attention you need.

Comment: I got it but that is why I have asked "how do I approach fixing sealed consumer product". Someone below already suggested iFixit.com and it is quite helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can prise clips apart with a plastic tool ("spudger" or "pry tool") around the edges between two halves of the plastic shell. Sometimes sealed is genuinely sealed and can't be opened non-destructively.

iFixit.com is also a good resource for this question in general.